# CTRL_BREAK_EVENT to a GUI application will compromise parent process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I created a console application with code beneath.

Those code will just start a child process of the explorer.exe then send a CTRL_BREAK_EVENT to it which is expected to be a NO-OP since the child explorer process is not a console application. Then using TerminateProcess to kill the child process which had no effect either but it's ok too.

The problem is, after those steps, the whole console event system for this parent process is broken - I cannot shutdown this console application by clicking X on the console window nor by pressing CTRL-C.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const LPWSTR exe = const_cast<LPTSTR>(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"));

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    CreateProcess(exe,
        exe,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi);

    Sleep(1000);
    GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, pi.dwProcessId);
    Sleep(1000);
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
    Sleep(1000);
    while (true) {
        Sleep(1000);
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
}
```

I do this because I'm making an application hosting platform that people can upload and run applications on a private cloud. We don't know what kinds of EXEs users will upload. If user uploads a console application that relying on CTRL_BREAK_EVENT for a graceful exit, we want to make it possible, so we try CTRL_BREAK_EVENT first. If the program doesn't shutdown in time after a while (for example a GUI program) we will kill it, just like the code above did. We don't want it to break the whole console control event system if we do this on a GUI application since we rely on it to manage lifecycles other services which run as children processes.

By the way, if we created the process with creation flag "DETACHED_PROCESS", the breaking of console control event system will break too even the EXE is a console application.

Any idea to workaround this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Add CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE?

Comment: @Anders unfortunately still the same

Comment: What if you replace Explorer with an actual console application?

Comment: [It is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-process-groups) and I can reproduce on Windows10 but Windows11. Which version is your system?

Comment: @Anders console application works normal. The problem is with the gui application. I use explorer.exe in the example code just for convenience. This problem occurs on any gui application as a subprocess of a console application.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT no the document mentioned nothing about the issue. The issue is the "break" mechanism of the parent process is compromised. No doc has ever mentioned "break" a gui subprocess would compromise parent process. I found this issue on Windows 10. But for 11, I assume you have set Windows Terminal as default console and tested with opening test program instantly? Try with classic console, or run your test exe from already opened console, then press CTRL-C, it will be the same to Windows 10.

Comment: Well, the docs say "When a process uses the CreateProcess function to **create a new console process**, it can specify the CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP flag to make the new process the root process of a console process group. " so it is unclear what the new group flag means for a GUI child process.

Comment: @Anders The NEW PROCESS GROUP is meaningful for GUI process too. The concept of PROCESS GROUP is not only for break event, but it's another story.

Comment: [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent) Sends a specified signal to a **console** process group. It's undefined behavior, which is not recognized as BUG, for sending to a GUI process group after consulting.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT But does winapi have a function to check if the process is a console or GUI? Btw you can name this thing any name, even call it a feature, but doesn't change the fact that a reasonable winapi use is causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to prevent this issue from occuring which I use currently in our production, for anyone who is facing the same issue.

1. Use `QueryFullProcessImageName` to find the PE image file path of the child process.
2. Find the subsystem of this PE image. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format
3. If the subsystem is GUI, don't use `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` on it.

If you are not familiar with PE format and don't want to read the doc, just do this:

1. Read at `0x3c` as `UINT16` of the PE file to find the offset of PE header.
2. Read `UINT8` at `PE_HEADER + 0x18 + 0x44`, and `0x02` means a GUI application.

I would like to not mark this as an answer since I'm hoping some more elegant way.